# adding counter in enhanced for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach, counter

I have a code which takes name and number from user and save those in an arraylist as object.

I am using this enhanced for loop to printout all name and number which is stored in that arraylist ...

```
for(Objectclass p : Test) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName() + "   Number: " + p.getNumber());
    }
```

it prints like **Name: blah blah  Number: blah blah**

now i want to add counter number before Name and number like 
**1.Name: blah blah  Number: blah blah
2.Name ... number 
3.Name ... number**

... how can i add that ? if i use another for loop inside this for loop to add counter number ... it prints again and again.

Comment: My opinion is that if you need the index, you should stick to the old `for` loop with index variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a counter variable declared outside of the enhanced for-loop.

```
int i = 0;
for(Objectclass p : Test) {
    System.out.println(++i + ". Name: " + p.getName() + "   Number: " + p.getNumber());
}
```

Or so, you don't have a useless variable after it, switch back to the old method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Test.size();){
    Objectclass p = Test.get(i++);
    System.out.println(i + ". Name: " + p.getName() + "   Number: " + p.getNumber());
 }
```

Comment: Another way to avoid the "useless variable" would be to wrap another block around the whole lot for local scoping - `{ int i = 0; for(...){...} }`

Comment: @IanRoberts Well, if you need the index, sticking to the old method is IMHO much simpler and more readable.

Comment: and if i want to print out index number instead of counter how can i do that?

Comment: In the top method, change the counter from `++i` to `i++` and it'll print the index.

Comment: @Joffrey assuming a random access list, yes, but if you just have a List and don't know if it's an ArrayList or a LinkedList then it's better to stick with the iterator-based traversal.

Comment: @IanRoberts Indeed, that's better for performance. I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int i = 0;
for(Objectclass p : Test) 
{
    i++;
    System.out.println(i + ". Name: " + p.getName() + "   Number: " + p.getNumber());
}
```

Sadly, there is no way of extracting an iteration index from an enhanced for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly try -

```
for(Objectclass p : Test) {
    System.out.println("Index: " + Test.indexOf(p+1) + "Name: " + p.getName() + "   Number:    " + p.getNumber());
}
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining what you've added? (And I think you've got the +1 in the wrong place)